# How to remove/adjust Title in the Home.aspx with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way to modify the title in my Home page (/SiteAssets/Home.aspx) as removing a "New" word with SharePoint 2010. I have edited in the `v4.master` page. However, it did not affect to my Home page. Besides that, I cannot find any file that has the code. Please take a look at an image below. Please let me know if I miss something to do for that change.

```
<td style="color:#185591;font-size:2.0em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif">
    <marquee>
        Welcome to the portal
    </marquee>
</td>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you both check in and approve the master page after making the change?

Comment: @RandyH. I used SharePoint Designer and overwrite the current page. Moreover, I have downloaded the `v4.master` and edited that file with notepad and then upload it to the SharePoint. Sadly, nothing happened...

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are using the `v4.master` page and not some other master page? You can check this by going to `Site Actions > Site Settings > Look and Feel (Master Page)`

Comment: AFAIK, all master page changes require approval. It's especially confusing  because SharePoint Designer does not give any indication that the Approval Status is still "Pending". Try going to /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx for the site in question and make sure that v4.master has been approved.

Answer (score 1):

I just find the solution to solve issue. This requires you to have or install the SharePoint Designer. After making some changes with any page, you would like to public these changes to the Homepage as my desire, just simply do it as 2-step below:

1. Select a master page such as `v4.master`
2. Click on `Set as Default`
3. Click your result

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used 2010 for a long time...

To me this does **not** look like it is part of the original SharePoint 2010 design.

Did someone use the *ductape approach* and injected it with some other script?

Open up F12 developer tools, and do a search on all scriptfiles.

Note: Marquee is an obsolete HTML tag, not garanteed to work in browsers any more.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It somehow helps me a lots to find out a solution. Please reference to my answer as below to address the problem.